# Округление числа python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В выходной файл надо вывести вещественное число с округлением до n-ого знака после запятой. Как это сделать?

Comment: В питоне уже несколько лет как нет типа  long. Во float используйте точку, а не запятую. Код вставляйте текстом, а не картинкой. Не используйте min в качестве имени переменной - это встроенная функция.

Comment: Спасибо! Про лонг вообще неожиданно. В случае больших чисел в таком случае просто использовать int?

Comment: Да.  Что вы понимаете под большими числами?

Comment: Ну 10 в сотой степени например

Comment: Да, это тоже int. Проверка - print(type(10**100)) Хотя sys.maxsize покажет вам намного меньше :)

Comment: Спасибо вам))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round(number[, ndigits])` - округляет число number до ndigits знаков после запятой (по умолчанию, до нуля знаков, то есть, до ближайшего целого)

```
In [37]: n = 33/7                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [38]: n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[38]: 4.714285714285714

In [39]: round(n, 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[39]: 4.7

In [40]: round(n, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[40]: 4.7143
```

[Ссылка на англоязычную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round)